# amazon AWS RDS and Django not playing well

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am trying to run the command `./manage.py loaddata` to populate my rds postgres db, however when i run it the command just hangs forevor. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: did you confirm the RDS server is reachable ?

Comment: yes, i can run other `./manage.py` commands such as `migrate`

Comment: How long did you wait before deciding it was forever?  Did you look at the database activity levels using RDS monitoring tools?  How about network traffic from machine where python is to the database machine?  What does "top" show you on the python machine?  How about "strace" of the python process?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the process has been killed by the OS.

When I tried it locally I got no message exactly as you mentioned, when I tried it using AWS cloud9 IDE I received the message 'killed'.

I upgraded the cloud9 instance type and it worked.